# Interpret Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to document an english interpretation of a validation rule that uses a regular expresion. I have two areas that i cannot figure out, and i have searh all over and can not find any information on the pieces of the expression i identifed below:

```
[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]
```

What i have interpretted so far (from the above snippet) is that this lists the characters that are not allowed, those between the `[^ and ]`. There is one set of double back slashes and that means a single backslash character. The part I can't figure out is the `\s@\""`  I see that \s means white space, i am assuming the @ is the character it represents but I dont know what the `\""` means. I am also not sure if the backslashes around s@ are delimiters of some sort, which      changes my interpretation above.

The other piece I can't interpret is this:

```
\"".+\""
```

There is no definiton (at least that i can find) for \" or \""
I am under the impression that backslashes should not be stand alone, that is they either escape some special character or are used in a pair to denote teh backslash itself.

If it helps the complete regex is:

```
^((([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+)*)|(\"".+\""))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})))$
```

Thnaks for any help!

Comment: Which language is being used to process this. My understanding is the same as yours. The only open item perhaps for you is the \""

Comment: The OP seems to note in FRoZeN's answer that the regex is used by an external party, so this is possibly not a regex used in Java code.

Comment: You need to post the actual code in which the regex is written (as presented to the compiler). The language specific escaping of quotes, backslashes and oter metacharacters are a tricky-wicket. The string interpretation requires one set of escaping and the regex engine requires another. They are processed in series.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that this regex is written in a language in which the double-quote character is escaped by having two together. I think maybe VB(.Net) does this..?

In which case `\""` would be parsed by this language as `\"`, which would then be parsed in a regular expression as `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be complicated to understand

basicly the square parentesis `[]` means that the expression will match any of the characters inside them. `\s` an expression for a space

Try http://www.regular-expressions.info/

also i can highly recommend [Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/create.html) it also has wording for expressions. it also generates code for you to make sure you escape characters correctly.

Since `\` is both an escape character in programming languages, and a character that is used to define things in the expressions, you can get into some situations that make your expressions hard to read.

It looks like that is what you are having issues with with `\""`

the other part: `\"".+\""` seem to match `double quote followed by any character one to unlimited times and then ending in another double quote`
The issue is with how the programming language you use makes sure to get those double qoutes inside the expression, and not count as code i believe.

Comment: ah, wasnt looking at the plus sign as cardinality, good point. This is actually a regex used by an external company that we send informatio to , so I am going to go back to them with this, Because as you point out maybe this is something specific to them or how they process this data, their programming language etc... I just thought that I should be able to find information about everything within a regex, but as some of you point out i guess that is not necessarily true. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Given your original regex:

```
^((([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+)*)|(\"".+\""))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})))$
```

I've deciphered this and written it out in free-spacing mode with comments. I'm presenting this here in Python's raw text format so that you can see the native regex as it is being presented to the regex engine (after string interpretation):

### Original expression commented in native regex:

```py
re_commented = r'''
    # Match an email address.
    ^                                 # Anchor to start of string.
    (                                 # ($1:) Entire string.
      (                               # $2: FIRST PART (before @).
        ( [^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+     # ($3:) Either one
          (                           # ($4:) or more
            \.                        #       dot separated
            [^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+   #       parts.
          )*                          # ($4:)
        )                             # ($3:)
      | (                             # ($5:) Or FIRST PART is
          \"".+\""                    # a doubly, double quoted string.
        )                             # ($5:)
      )                               # $2: FIRST PART (before @).
      @                               # Required @ separates parts.
      (                               # $6: LAST PART (after @).
        ( \[                          # ($7:) LAST PART is Either
          [0-9]{1,3}\.                # an IPv4 domain address
          [0-9]{1,3}\.                # (i.e. 10.0.0.255)
          [0-9]{1,3}\.                # between
          [0-9]{1,3}                  # square
          \]                          # brackets.
        )                             # ($7:)
      | (                             # ($8:) Or LAST PART is
          ([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+         # a DNS style dot separated
          [a-zA-Z]{2,}                # named domain.
        )                             # ($8:)
      )                               # $6: LAST PART (after @).
    )                                 # ($1:) Entire string.
    $                                 # Anchor to end of string.
    '''
```

As you can now clearly see, this regex is attempting to validate an email address. It also appears someone has gone in and edited the file and mangled the double quotes - (Each instance of `\""` should be just `"` *as seen bt the regex engine*). Note also that the `\""` sequence does no harm when inside a character class, as it is equivalent to a single instance of a double quote. However, it is causing mischief where it appears as the second alternative of the FIRST PART of the email, i.e. `\"".+\""`. Here is a corrected version which fixes the problem with the double quotes. I've presented it here fully commented in free-spaciong mode and in the form of a Java snippet demonstrating proper escaping of all quotes and backslashes.

### Repaired expression commented in Java regex string:

```java
Pattern re_valid = Pattern.compile(
    "    # Match an email address. (Rev:20121105_1100 fixed quotes.)        \n" +
    "    ^                                     # Anchor to start of string. \n" +
    "    (                                     # ($1:) Entire string.       \n" +
    "      (                                   # $2: FIRST PART (before @). \n" +
    "        ( [^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+    # ($3:) Either one           \n" +
    "          (                               # ($4:) or more              \n" +
    "            \\.                           #       dot separated        \n" +
    "            [^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+  #       parts.               \n" +
    "          )*                              # ($4:)                      \n" +
    "        )                                 # ($3:)                      \n" +
    "      | (                                 # ($5:) Or FIRST PART is     \n" +
    "          \".+\"                          # a double quoted string.    \n" +
    "        )                                 # ($5:)                      \n" +
    "      )                                   # $2: FIRST PART (before @). \n" +
    "      @                                   # Required @ separates parts.\n" +
    "      (                                   # $6: LAST PART (after @).   \n" +
    "        ( \\[                             # ($7:) LAST PART is Either  \n" +
    "          [0-9]{1,3}\\.                   # an IPv4 domain address     \n" +
    "          [0-9]{1,3}\\.                   # (i.e. 10.0.0.255)          \n" +
    "          [0-9]{1,3}\\.                   # between                    \n" +
    "          [0-9]{1,3}                      # square                     \n" +
    "          \\]                             # brackets.                  \n" +
    "        )                                 # ($7:)                      \n" +
    "      | (                                 # ($8:) Or LAST PART is      \n" +
    "          ([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+           # a DNS style dot separated  \n" +
    "          [a-zA-Z]{2,}                    # named domain.              \n" +
    "        )                                 # ($8:)                      \n" +
    "      )                                   # $6: LAST PART (after @).   \n" +
    "    )                                     # ($1:) Entire string.       \n" +
    "    $                                     # Anchor to end of string.   ", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

Note that there are other mostly minor issues with this regex (Google "email validation" for more.) Also, many of the grouping parentheses are unnecessary.

One last comment - *Java sucks when it comes to writing and commenting regexes!*

Comment: Awesome break down, thanks for the information and for the effort. I have enough to go on. Also, i was a little rigid in my thinking that every piece of the experssion was to be taken literally in a regex and had a meaning. Things can vary depending on the language of the application. Thanks again and to all that responded.